# Inheritance: only fields and methods?

Tags: c#, .net

Reading a book it says that the derived class inherits all fields and methods...but what about properties??

Comment: I would like to know why its not mentioned..

Comment: Probably you're reading a book about a language which doesn't have `properties` concept? Properties are inherited in C#.

Comment: Which book, and can you post the paragraph that says this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A derived class inherits all methods fields and, yes, properties too, although private methods, fields and properties are generally not directly accessible or visible from the derived class unless it is nested in it's superclass (the parent). Constructors and finalizers, however, are not inherited so when you derive a type you always need to code any constructors that are required for your object initialization, even if it just calls down to the base class's constructor.

However, it is generally considered good practice to make your fields private and allow access to them, if necessary, to derived classes via properties. That way it allows you, the author of the base class, to have confidence that you control the way in which the classes state (the value of it's fields) can change.

To illustrate you question about properties:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Name { get; set; }
    public void Greet()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}

public class Child : Person
{
   public Nickname { get; set;}
}
```

In the above example, the derived class, Child, has a nickname (a property) *in addition to* its derived property (Name) and its derived method (Greet).

Comment: @Ocelot20: Static and private members are certainly inherited! Try it! class B { private int x; private static void M(int y ) { } class D : B { void N() { M(this.x); } } } How is that legal if M and x are not inherited by D from B??? **Constructors and destructors** are what are not inherited. Privates and statics most certainly are.

Comment: @Eric - wasn't happy with the comment about static myself [which is why I had that kludged qualifying comment in square brackets - now removed]. I wanted to explain that static members are not overridable and not part of the instance itself, and not wanting to overload a newbie with lots of terminology. Probably would have been simpler to just not mention static in the context of this question. As for private members - I see what you mean. My answer confuses the notion of being/not being inherited, with being/not being directly accessible from the inherited class. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Maybe I'm confused, but with your example I get two errrors: `M(int)` is inaccessable due to its protection level, and same for `x`.

Comment: @Ocelot20: You have made a typing error. **D is inside B.** But that's actually irrelevant. Let's consider your case where D is not inside B. **Why would you get an accessibility error if the members x and M were not inherited**?  The *reason* you get an accessibility error is *because* the members are inherited! If the members were not inherited then *how would the compiler know which member to check for inaccessibility?*

Comment: @Ocelot20: Look at it like this. Suppose you had class P { private int x; } class Q { Console.WriteLine(x); }. P and Q have no relationship, so x is not inherited. The error is not "*x is private*". The error is "*there isn't any member called x*". It is the fact that private members are inherited which enables the accessibility error to be generated in the first place in the class B / class D scenario. The accessibility error is *evidence* that the private member is inherited; why do you believe that it is evidence that it is *not* inherited?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: You're right. I guess I was confusing what inherited members are "available for use" with what is actually being inherited. Of course your example shows I would have been wrong either way. Guess you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a considerable amount of misinformation in the answers here. For the correct answer, see section 3.4 of the C# specification, which I reproduce for you here:

> Members of a type are either declared in the type declaration or inherited from the base class of the type. When a type inherits from a base class, **all members of the base class, except instance constructors, destructors and static constructors, become members of the derived type**. The declared accessibility of a base class member does not control whether the member is inherited—inheritance extends to any member that isn’t an instance constructor, static constructor, or destructor. However, an inherited member may not be accessible in a derived type, either because of its declared accessibility or because it is hidden by a declaration in the type itself.

I have added some emphasis to the relevant part. The key is that **all members are inherited** except for constructors and destructors. Members are inherited regardless of whether they are methods, fields, properties, events or indexers. Members are inherited regardless of whether they are public, private or protected.  Members are inherited regardless of whether they are static, instance, virtual or abstract. **All members are inherited**.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes, properties are inherited along with the fields and the methods. Both private and public methods, fields and properties are inherited, but private members are inaccessible by the child class (unless the child class is nested within the base class - scoping and inheritance are connected but different things).

Properties, as implemented in C# (and most other languages that support them) are just a code-level abstract for a pair of methods that `get` and `set` the property, so having a `int` property called `Age`, is syntactic sugar for a couple of methods that are called `int GetAge()` and `SetAge(int value)`, so it's natural that any rules that apply to methods applies evently to properties too.

Comment: Private members are accessible by the derived class if the derived class is in the accessibility domain, ie, nested in the base class.

Comment: I'll edit the answer, but that is an edge case, and not one most people will encounter on their own, as it involves changing the base class to add a child class.

Answer (score 0):

A property is syntactic sugar for a Get_ and Set_ method.
In other words: the compiler translates a property to one or two methods.  So, they're inherited as well. :)